# Conditional in bottomtab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm starting with React Native and I have this little issue right here. I have a bottomTabNavigator, if the user has permission, he navigates to ImageScreen, else, it navigates to the HomeScreen.

My function global.hasPermission() checks the permission and return true or false, so I want to be capable of changing the {screen: ImageScreen} depending on what the function returns. How can I do it? Where do I call my function hasPermission()?

Here's my tabNavigator:

```
const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Image: {
        screen: ImageScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Image Screen',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => (
                <Ionicons
                    name={'ios-camera'}
                    size={focused ? 30 : 26}
                    style={{ color: tintColor }}
                />
            ),
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my app I handle the Authentication throught **React Context API** ( https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html )

Some days ago I replied to a similar question, you can see how to create use the context here: [How Redirect to Login if page is protected and the user is not signed in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847623/how-redirect-to-login-if-page-is-protected-and-the-user-is-not-signed-in/55850064#55850064)

Like my previous answer, you can check user permission into *ImageScreen*'s **componentDidMount ()** and, iof he has no permission, you can redirect it to your home screen like this (assuming you home screen is contained into Stack Navigator):

```js
// into your ImageScreen
componentDidMount () {
  const hasPermission = YourFunctionWhichReturnsTrueOrFalse()
  if (!hasPermission) this.props.navigation.navigate('home') // the title of your home screen here
}
```